# Шаблон "Фабричный метод". В чём преимущества данного паттерна?

Tags: рефакторинг, шаблоны-проектирования

На странице https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/factory-method написано, что основная задача, которую решает данный паттерн - это избавление кода от привязки к конкретным классам.

Вот пример кода, который там приведён:

```
// Паттерн Фабричный метод применим тогда, когда в программе
// есть иерархия классов продуктов.
interface Button is
    method render()
    method onClick(f)

class WindowsButton implements Button is
    method render(a, b) is
        // Отрисовать кнопку в стиле Windows.
    method onClick(f) is
        // Навесить на кнопку обработчик событий Windows.

class HTMLButton implements Button is
    method render(a, b) is
        // Вернуть HTML-код кнопки.
    method onClick(f) is
        // Навесить на кнопку обработчик события браузера.


// Базовый класс фабрики. Заметьте, что "фабрика" — это всего
// лишь дополнительная роль для класса. Скорее всего, он уже
// имеет какую-то бизнес-логику, в которой требуется создание
// разнообразных продуктов.
class Dialog is
    method render() is
        // Чтобы использовать фабричный метод, вы должны
        // убедиться в том, что эта бизнес-логика не зависит от
        // конкретных классов продуктов. Button — это общий
        // интерфейс кнопок, поэтому все хорошо.
        Button okButton = createButton()
        okButton.onClick(closeDialog)
        okButton.render()

    // Мы выносим весь код создания продуктов в особый метод,
    // который назвают "фабричным".
    abstract method createButton():Button


// Конкретные фабрики переопределяют фабричный метод и
// возвращают из него собственные продукты.
class WindowsDialog extends Dialog is
    method createButton():Button is
        return new WindowsButton()

class WebDialog extends Dialog is
    method createButton():Button is
        return new HTMLButton()


class Application is
    field dialog: Dialog

    // Приложение создаёт определённую фабрику в зависимости от
    // конфигурации или окружения.
    method initialize() is
        config = readApplicationConfigFile()

        if (config.OS == "Windows") then
            dialog = new WindowsDialog()
        else if (config.OS == "Web") then
            dialog = new WebDialog()
        else
            throw new Exception("Error! Unknown operating system.")

    // Если весь остальной клиентский код работает с фабриками и
    // продуктами только через общий интерфейс, то для него
    // будет не важно, какая фабрика была создана изначально.
    method main() is
        this.initialize()
        dialog.render()
```

Но мне непонятен этот пример. Фабрика мне тут кажется бессмысленной, поскольку я и без неё могу избавить код от привязки к конкретным классам. Вот тот же пример, который я переписал без фабрик и привязки клиентского кода к конкретным классам:

```
interface Button is
    method render()
    method onClick(f)

class WindowsButton implements Button is
    method render(a, b) is
        // Отрисовать кнопку в стиле Windows.
    method onClick(f) is
        // Навесить на кнопку обработчик событий Windows.

class HTMLButton implements Button is
    method render(a, b) is
        // Вернуть HTML-код кнопки.
    method onClick(f) is
        // Навесить на кнопку обработчик события браузера.


class Application is
    // нет привязки к конкретной кнопке
    field button: Button

    method initialize() is
        config = readApplicationConfigFile()

        if (config.OS == "Windows") then
            button = new WindowsButton()
        else if (config.OS == "Web") then
            button = new HTMLButton()
        else
            throw new Exception("Error! Unknown operating system.")

    method main() is
        this.initialize()
        button.render()
```

Вопрос: какая разница между двумя примерами? Какие преимущества дают фабрики?
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

**Когда следует использовать фабричный метод**

1. Когда заранее неизвестно, объекты каких типов необходимо создавать;
2. Когда система должна быть независимой от процесса создания новых объектов и расширяемой: в нее можно легко вводить новые классы, объекты которых система должна создавать;
3. Когда создание новых объектов необходимо делегировать из базового класса классам наследникам;

Если объяснения на данном вам сайте не устраивают то посмотрите подробнее [тут](https://bool.dev/blog/detail/porozhdayushchie-patterny-fabrichnyy-metod)

Answer (score 2):

Из [Design Pattern - GoF](https://g.co/kgs/2TpEDW):

> Определяет интерфейс для создания объекта, но **оставляет подклассам** решение о том, какой класс инстанцировать. Фабричный метод **позволяет** классу **делегировать инстанцирование подклассам**.

Важный момент в том, что инстанцирование осуществляется подклассами. В случае:

```
if (config.OS == "Windows") then
    button = new WindowsButton()
else if (config.OS == "Web") then
    button = new HTMLButton()
else
    throw new Exception("Error! Unknown operating system.")
```

осуществляется прямое создание интересующих объектов.

А что если приложение достаточно масштабное, и мест, где можно создать `WindowsButton` или `HTMLButton` в коде больше одного? Больше двух? Больше сотни?

А что если нужно создавать не только кнопки, но еще и `Label`, `TextEdit`, `RadioButton` и т.п.?

Прописать везде условный оператор? Или проще объявить пару классов:

```
class WindowsCreator implements Creator is
    method createButton() is
        // вернуть Windows кнопку
    
    method createLabel() is
        // вернуть Windows label

    // и т.д.

class HTMLCreator implements Creator is
    method createButton() is
        // вернуть HTML код кнопки

    method createLabel() is
        // вернуть HTML код label

    // и т.д.
```

Имхо, проще создать пару классов, и затем жонглировать ими как душе угодно. Остается на этапе инициализации определить нужный класс `Creator`, аналогично как в приведенном примере. Затем можно использовать методы создания сколько угодно раз и где угодно, не будучи привязанным к конкретным классам.

Comment: Что проще (и понятнее) зависит от идиом языка и масштабов бедствия. Например С++ может использовать шаблонный метод и CRTP, фабричный метод можно комбинировать с другими порождающими и поведенческими шаблонами, как правило фабричный метод нужен для исключения повтора кода который должен сопровождать создание новых объектов и он везде один и тот же или создание происходит через делегацию ответсвенности

Comment: "А что если приложение достаточно масштабное, и мест, где можно создать WindowsButton или HTMLButton в коде больше одного? Больше двух? Больше сотни?"

Ведь в примере, который приведён на сайте https://refactoring.guru, тоже есть условный оператор:

if (config.OS == "Windows") then
            dialog = new WindowsDialog()
        else if (config.OS == "Web") then
            dialog = new WebDialog()
        else
            throw new Exception("Error! Unknown operating system.")

Мне опять придётся писать это условие везде.

Comment: @NewPerson, в том и дело, что не придется. Это условие пишется один раз, в нем определяется тип фабрики. Дальше во всех остальных местах для создания конкретных объектов вызываются методы конкретной (уже определенной **одним условием**) фабрики. Нужно что-то поменять? Поменяли в том месте, где создается фабрика. Остальной код остался без изменений.

Comment: @Bogdan, получается пример на сайте refactoring.guru не имеет смысла? Ведь там эти условия не инкапсулированы в отдельный метод.

Comment: @NewPerson, задача паттерна - инкапсулировать в отдельные методы не условные операторы, а обращения к `new` при создании конкретных (в вашем случае `HTMLButton` или `WindowsButton`) классов. В примере на сайте это и сделано (нет прямого обращения к `new WindowsButton` или `new HTMLButton`). Здесь вся фишка не в том, чтобы уйти от условного оператора, а в том, чтобы определиться, **что именно** создается в условном операторе. Используя фабричный метод, будет один условный оператор, выбирающий "фабрику". А все остальные классы напрямую вызывают методы фабрики без условных операторов.

Comment: А как пользоваться единожды созданной фабрикой из различных точек программы? Через глобальную переменную? В примере это Application.field.

Comment: Честно, никак не могу понять смысл паттерна и примера на сайте refactoring.guru.
Если бы код инстанциирования объекта был бы сложным, тогда можно было бы понять для чего нужны эти фабрики. Хотя для этого, насколько я знаю, существует другой паттерн -- Билдер. А тут в примере это обёртки да и только.